# change particular area of an image and fill color in that area

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, html, html5-canvas

Edit Png  Image For E.g change particular area and fill color in that area.

I want to change the color of an image only selected area. Like the first user selects a color then he chooses an image after that he can change the particular area of image color with the selected color.

After that he can save that image too Is it possible?? like Color company website uses this kind of thing.

like below URL https://www.sherwin-williams.com/visualizer#/active

Comment: Show what you've tried...

Comment: @YashParekh as of now i am changing image color with css.

Comment: Okay, what else have you tried besides that? Please, at least use google and check out some articles about it. [**Like this.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Demo:

Full page: https://angularjs-rj88cu.stackblitz.io/

Code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-rj88cu

### Explanation:

The editor is an svg containing background image as `<image>` and areas as `<path>` both are created from `editor.imageUrl` and `editor.areas`

For downloading,

1. Background image is drawn on a canvas
2. SVG (without `<image>`) is converted to dataUrl and then drawn on canvas
3. Canvas is converted to dataUrl for downloading

Why canvas was not used instead of svg in the first place?

Because mouse interaction are difficult to implement in canvas and is much easier in inline svg as the work like DOM elements (hover pseudo class, click events, etc)

Also I assumed you wanted angularjs because you have tagged it (even though you have not mentioned in the question)

Also there are a lot of bad practices in the code like editor not being a component and styling `input[type=color]`'s Shadow DOM (you can use some colorpicker plugin instead)

PS: Tell me if something needs to be changed

Comment: hii thanks for your reply . Can you describe full code here and it will be very helpful if you see sherwin-williams.com/visualizer#/active this url. Need something like this

Comment: @user3198563 1. The code is pretty self-explanatory, you can ask me which parts you didn't understand. 2. I have made as per the link in the first place and it is very similar, if you want something additional please be specific and I'll help you out. 3. Do you think my answer is the best at this point as compared to other answers?

Comment: yes as compared to other your answer is good. See first i have to select color from color picker, in second step i have to select any area of the pic . Then  selected area will be automatically filed with selected color

Comment: and can you use full image of wall

Comment: I'll update the color change mechanism soon... And what do mean by "full image of wall"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173801/discussion-between-user3198563-and-devansh-j).

Answer (score 9):

Edit: Its Possible to get the image data from a canvas and change its pixels. You could also search for algorithms for drawing lines, circles and etc. But the ideia is still the same (Get a canvas image, Edit it, then save it).

Since you are using AngularJS, you can create a directive that gets the color as input and plots that color on a specific area of the image. Then you can use the `canvas.toDataURL()` or `canvas2image()` method to parse the canvas into an image with the desired format.

Check the MDN docs for this method here https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

I have made a small code snippet just to give you an ideia. I think that the color picker feature is a step that you can easely implement and deliver as input to your canvas directive. I hope that helps!

```js
function hexToRgb(color) {
    var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
    color = color.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
        return r + r + g + g + b + b;
    });
    
    var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(color);
    return result ? {
        r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
        g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
        b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
    } : {
        r: 0,
        g: 0,
        b: 0
    };
}

function colorImage(imgId,hexaColor) {
    // create hidden canvas (using image dimensions)
    var imgElement = document.getElementById(imgId);
  
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = imgElement.width;
    canvas.height = imgElement.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(imgElement,0,0);
    
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    
    var data = imageData.data;
  
    // convert image to grayscale
    var rgbColor = hexToRgb(hexaColor);
    //console.log(rgbColor);
    
    for(var p = 0, len = data.length; p < len; p+=4) {
        //if(data[p+3] == 0)
        //   continue;
        data[p + 0] = rgbColor.r;
        data[p + 1] = rgbColor.g;
        data[p + 2] = rgbColor.b;
        //data[p + 3] = 255;
    }
    ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    // replace image source with canvas data
    imgElement.src = canvas.toDataURL();
}

// changing color of capsule on select event
document.getElementById('sel_top').onchange = function(){
    colorImage('img_top', this.value);
}
document.getElementById('sel_bottom').onchange = function(){
    colorImage('img_bottom', this.value);
}

$('input[type="color"]').on("change", function(color) {
      console.log(this.value);
      var colorHex = this.value;
   
      colorImage('img_top',colorHex);
 });
```

```css
img.color-img {
 position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.slim.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinyColorPicker/1.1.1/jqColorPicker.min.js"></script>

<label for="sel_top">top color: </label>
  <select id="sel_top">
   <option value="#ffffff">select</option>
      <option value="#ff0000">red</option>
      <option value="#00ff00">green</option>
      <option value="#0000ff">blue</option>
      <option value="#FCF153">yellow</option>    
  </select>
  <label for="sel_top">bottom color: </label>
  <select id="sel_bottom">
      <option value="#ffffff">select</option>
      <option value="#ff0000">red</option>
      <option value="#00ff00">green</option>
      <option value="#0000ff">blue</option>
      <option value="#FCF153">yellow</option>    
  </select>
    <div>
      <input type="color" value="#ff0000" class="myColorPic">
    </div>
  <br><br>
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
  
  <img id="img_top" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="color-img" />
  <img id="img_bottom" src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="color-img" />
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,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" class="color-img" />
```

Comment: Hi i want to change color of an image , daont want to draw

Comment: Still the ideia is the same. I have made some changes on the code in order to change the image color. I hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your reply... can you make like first user picks a color then he can select any area of an image and selected color will go there. Area means a home inner image

Comment: To select an area and do whatever you want to the selected image please check similar questions like here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35316667/how-to-make-selection-box-in-canvas-to-select-any-object-it-touches-not-only-obj and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32752547/html5-canvas-select-an-area-and-zoom

Comment: you referred two urls . both are not usable for me.  Please check this url please.

Comment: https://www.sherwin-williams.com/visualizer#/active please see this url

Comment: can you show example where user can choose color not from drop down but from color picker after that he can select particular area of an image add selected color will fill on that area

Comment: @user3198563 I have Added a color Pic to the snnipet. For image areas selection he could check a Jquery plugin that gives the coordinates of the selected area. I found a plugin on this link http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

Comment: hii that is not working ..... see i have two walls . i want to fill first wall only with selected color .. please helped me out

Answer (score 0):

The functional in the example - custom product, and it's implemented through AngularJS.

If you want to do something like this, you may combine several jQuery plugins and HTML5 features.

Things you need:

- some jQuery color picker - for choose color
- HTML5 canvas - for show borders and fill image areas with a color
- canvas2image - to save image

If you want to use some out of the box, just look for some
**jquery colorize image** plugin.

Comment: An html color picker enough. You can just use `<input type="color">` and use `input.value` to get the hex code

Comment: @awesomeguy hi thanks for your reply . I have done this thing already but that is not enough

Answer (score -1):

Just copy and paste this function in custom helper file or your class.
You just need to set parameter for proper image resolution result.

```
  function resize($source_image, $destination, $tn_w, $tn_h, $quality = 100, $wmsource = false) {
        $info = getimagesize($source_image);
        $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

        #assuming the mime type is correct
        switch ($imgtype) {
            case 'image/jpeg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            break;
            case 'image/jpg':
            $source = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_image);
            break;
            case 'image/gif':
            $source = imagecreatefromgif($source_image);
            break;
            case 'image/png':
            $source = imagecreatefrompng($source_image);
            break;
            default:
            die('Invalid image type.');
        }
        #Figure out the dimensions of the image and the dimensions of the desired thumbnail
        $src_w = imagesx($source);
        $src_h = imagesy($source);


        #Do some math to figure out which way we'll need to crop the image
        #to get it proportional to the new size, then crop or adjust as needed

        $x_ratio = $tn_w / $src_w;
        $y_ratio = $tn_h / $src_h;

        if (($src_w <= $tn_w) && ($src_h <= $tn_h)) {
            $new_w = $src_w;
            $new_h = $src_h;         
        } elseif (($x_ratio * $src_h) < $tn_h) {
            $new_h = ceil($x_ratio * $src_h);
            $new_w = $tn_w;
        } else {
            $new_w = ceil($y_ratio * $src_w);
            $new_h = $tn_h;
        }

        $newpic = imagecreatetruecolor(round($new_w), round($new_h));
        imagecopyresampled($newpic, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h, $src_w, $src_h);
        $final = imagecreatetruecolor($tn_w, $tn_h);
        $backgroundColor = imagecolorallocate($final, 248,248,248);
        imagefill($final, 0, 0, $backgroundColor);
        //imagecopyresampled($final, $newpic, 0, 0, ($x_mid - ($tn_w / 2)), ($y_mid - ($tn_h / 2)), $tn_w, $tn_h, $tn_w, $tn_h);
        imagecopy($final, $newpic, (($tn_w - $new_w)/ 2), (($tn_h - $new_h) / 2), 0, 0, $new_w, $new_h);
        

        #if we need to add a watermark
        if ($wmsource) {
            #find out what type of image the watermark is
            $info    = getimagesize($wmsource);
            $imgtype = image_type_to_mime_type($info[2]);

            #assuming the mime type is correct
            switch ($imgtype) {
                case 'image/jpeg':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromjpeg($wmsource);
                break;
                case 'image/gif':
                $watermark = imagecreatefromgif($wmsource);
                break;
                case 'image/png':
                $watermark = imagecreatefrompng($wmsource);
                break;
                default:
                die('Invalid watermark type.');
            }

            #if we're adding a watermark, figure out the size of the watermark
            #and then place the watermark image on the bottom right of the image
            $wm_w = imagesx($watermark);
            $wm_h = imagesy($watermark);
            imagecopy($final, $watermark, $tn_w - $wm_w, $tn_h - $wm_h, 0, 0, $tn_w, $tn_h);

        }
        if (imagejpeg($final, $destination, $quality)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: you answer should contain explanation not code only.